# Printer jobs in "pending" mode, but not printing

Tags: printing, canon

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Printer: Canon MX540

Problem: Printer worked initially. Suddenly stopped working. Printer cue just says "pending" and printing never happens.

/var/log/cups/error_log shows:

```
E [05/Sep/2023:21:41:42 +0200] [Job 19] No destination host name supplied by cups-browsed for printer \"Canon_MX530_series\", is cups-browsed running?
W [05/Sep/2023:21:41:42 +0200] [Job 19] Backend returned status 4 (stop printer)
E [05/Sep/2023:21:43:37 +0200] [Job 19] No destination host name supplied by cups-browsed for printer \"Canon_MX530_series\", is cups-browsed running?
W [05/Sep/2023:21:43:37 +0200] [Job 19] Backend returned status 4 (stop printer)
```

cups-browsed is running:

```
thorsten@tweedleburg:~$ ps -ef |grep browsed
root       11391       1  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it working, it seems to be a bug in cups-browsed, more here: [“No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128164/no-suitable-destination-host-found-by-cups-browsed)

To get it working, I removed cups-browsed:

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove cups-browsed
```

restarted cups:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

Deleted all printers manually: Settings -> Printers -> Canon MX530-series -> Settings -> Remove Printer
Added printer manually: Settings -> Printers -> Additional Printer Settings -> Add -> Network Printers

Comment: This was happening to my HP Color Laserjet with Ubuntu 22.04, where all jobs were paused and clicking the "Enable" policy caused the checkbox to clear itself after saving. Removing and re-adding the printer fixed it for me.